# Is TWebBrowser dependant on IE version?

Tags: windows, delphi, internet-explorer, twebbrowser

I am thinking about using the TWebBrowser component that comes within Delphi's default pallet of components in a project, but I wonder if it uses the IE version installed on the client machine?

If yes:
then I guess it would share its history, cookies, workoffline and stuff like that?
Can I separate them somehow?
Is there any webbrowser component that is free and is not shared with Internet Explorer on the client?

Comment: You asked if there's an alternative, not shared; yes.  There is. Chromium for Delphi.  uses webkit. basically the same as google chrome.

Comment: @Warren last version of DCE (http://www.progdigy.com/?p=204) is not a webkit wrapper, but actully uses out of process chrome.exe :-) There is also not feature-rich but pure Delphi component at http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer People also told about Mozilla Gecko wrapper but personally did not saw it. I wonder if ChromeFrame ActiveX can be naturally embedded into Delphi :-)

Comment: You should consider changing your accepted answer here, as the one you accepted is technically wrong.

Comment: @JerryDodge done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current answer is not quite correct. It appears for compatibility purposes, the WebBrowser control will run in IE7 Standards Mode by default unless you add some registry settings.

See:

- [WebBrowser Control Rendering Modes in IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx) <sup>*([archive](https://archive.ph/c1cfo))*</sup>
- [More IE8 Extensibility Improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) <sup>*([archive](https://archive.ph/cpJ6G))*</sup>

So it's not quite the current IE version. You can also check this if you use fiddler or check the web server logs for the agent string - as it alters the agent string used too!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, TWebBrowser uses whatever IE version is installed on the machine.
Take a look at this similar thread for some possible alternatives..

[How to embed a browser object, other than IE<n>, in a Delphi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162718/how-to-embed-a-browser-object-other-than-ien-in-a-delphi-application)

Comment: Do note that with IE8 installed, TWebBrowser (or more precisly, the underlying ActiveX IE component) defaults to IE7 mode.

Comment: How to switch to IE8 mode?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TWebBrowser is tied to Internet Explorer.  If you want a standalone HTML viewer, then look at the [PBear](http://www.pbear.com) components.

Comment: Remy - those are obsolete dead components. Fresh version is http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/

Also there is Google Chrome Embedded for Delphi with component at progdigy.com and people also told abouit Mozilla Gecko. So except for Opera that generally don't want their engine re-used, it seems all major HTML engines are available for Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

TWebBrowser is a wrapper around IE ActiveX interface. 
So, in the end,

```
 TWebBrowser = Internet Explorer
```